# Having trouble getting data from a website with JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I've just started out using JSoup to get small text from websites but I just can't figure out how to get the word "BONES" from the class "title":

```
<a href="https://anilist.co/studio/4/BONES" target="_blank" ng-show="b.studio.name">BONES</a>
```

Here's my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://anichart.net/Winter-2019").userAgent("mozilla/17.0").get();
        Elements temp = doc.select("div.title");

        for(Element s : temp) {
            System.out.println(s.getElementsByTag("a").text());
        }
```

Comment: does a tag inside title element? Also why not get all the link? `Elements temp = doc.select("a");`

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was really unclear. I want the word BONES between the tags <a> </a> not inside the link.

Comment: a is anchor tag which is a link i refer.

Comment: Yes, the tag BONES links you to another webpage. I just need the word BONES, not the link. I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: If you print the entire page `System.out.println(doc.html())` you will see that the page is demanding javascript enabled: 'Sorry, AniList requires Javascript.' So, the content you are looking for is not there.

Comment: Dang! Oh well, thanks for the help. Is there a way to make your comment as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

this page is generated by javascript using ajax, you can find the data in chrome dev tool:

[image]

Comment: I'm not really following how does this relate to getting a single element from the web page into java? I've never used ajax before. I know where the data is I just can't figure out how to get it in java.